# htaccess redirect url to witout extension with query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am getting this url `https://domain.com/user.php/123456`.
I want to redirect this url to `https://domain.com/user/123456` using htaccess.

My htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/(.+)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

I am internally processing this url by exploding the ("/") and getting the user information based on the query string id.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: I tried this but it is redirecting the url without the user id at the end like this `http://domain.com/user`

Comment: @Nag you basically want to get rid of `.php` if I am not wrong.

Comment: @Fakhruddin Ujjainwala Yes, but I shouldn't miss the query string at the end too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Rules.

```
 RewriteEngine on
#1--redirect from "user.php/foo" to "user/foo"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user\.php/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1 [L,R]
#2--rewrite "user/foo" to "user.php/foo"
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ /user.php/$1 [NC,L]
```